# A (very) slight extension of Mehta's integral

Tags: integration, random-matrices

I am interested in the value of the following integral, for $n\ge 2$:

$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-\frac 12 \lVert \lambda\rVert^2 + a_1 \lambda_1 + a_2 \lambda_2} \prod_{i < j} | \lambda_j - \lambda_i | \mathrm d \lambda_1 \dots \mathrm d \lambda_n
$$

When taking $a_1=a_2=0$, this reduces to Mehta's integral with $\gamma=1/2$. This question is a special case of [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212982/a-slight-generalization-of-mehtas-integral) on MO, which was not answered for $\gamma=1/2$. I am hoping that maybe 1) this case is simpler than the one proposed in the original question ; 2) seven years have passed and maybe someone has come up with an answer in-between!

I was hoping that maybe something like [Aomoto's variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_integral#Aomoto%27s_integral_formula) of Selberg's integral could be used to break the symmetry between the coefficients, but I cannot get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated!